# Using rails create method to call jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to have a create method in rails call a jQuery function?

I have two models @product and @photo with photo nested inside of product. I am  using [this JQuery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to handle photo upload being how it gives me a nice preview.

The problem is this plugin gives a 'start' button. When clicked it starts the upload of the photo before the creation of the product. So I am unable to connect the photo to the product. I am thinking of removing the 'start' button and just calling the function in the create action of the product.

Is that even possible?

Is that even a good idea?

```
  def create
  @product = current_user.products.create(params[:product])
  @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@photo.to_jq_image].to_json,
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }
        format.json { render json: {files: [@photo.to_jq_image]}, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an association so that `Product` `has_many :photos` and `Photo`belongs_to :product`. Then create a Photo on upload without providing product id.

When a product will `accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo` and you add a photo as a `fields_for` not a separate form then when saving product all assignments will be ok.

Refer to
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms/
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1